# Is there an issur to put cold water in a kli rishon on Yom Tov?

Tags: yom-tov, cooking-bishul

There is a prohibition of cooking to put cold water into a kli rishon of hot water on Shabbos. This is mentioned in the Mishna and Gemara on Shabbos 42a, and codified in the Tur and Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim siman 318 siff 9.

So for instance if you realize you don't have enough soup for all your guests, you may not remove the pot from the fire and add more water. This is assur even without putting the pot back on the flame, as the soup is in a kli rishon.

My question concerns Yom Tov. Does this prohibition apply to cases where cooking on Yom Tov is prohibited? See Shulchan Aruch siman 503 1 where we see it is not allowed to cook on one day of Yom Tov for the next. See also siman  512 for instances where cooking for certain people is not allowed, and even adding food to an already cooking pot is not allowed.

So in the aforementioned example, would putting the cold water in the soup pot which is not on the fire be allowed on Yom Tov?

Do to the nature of this question, I would prefer sourced answers.

What I've seen so far is the Rosh Yosef on the sugya who would have liked to assume the prohibition was  midirabanan. We could've built off this and say the prohibition was not extended to Yom Tov. However, the Rosh Yosef goes on to say the implications from the gemara and Beis Yosef are that it is a biblically prohibited act. I'm not clear what his implications are, but if it is biblical, I would assume there is no room to be lenient on Yom Tov.

Comment: You are allowed to cook on yom tov - why would this be a problem?

Comment: @wbf there are situations where it is assur to cook on yom tov. I will be editing for clarity soon.

Comment: @Lee I've edited for clarity. Thank you for your time, but I hope you see now that my question was concerning something else.

Comment: I would imagine that if one isn't allowed to prepare for the second day one isn't allowed to add water even if it isn't cooking. But the example of not being allowed to cook for someone is an interesting question, so +1.

Comment: @Yishai hmmm good point. Although there are situations where we can be meikel acc to ramma end of 495. So I'm not so sure this would be a case of issur.

Comment: I would think your question boils down (no pun intended) to whether or not this is considered cooking.

Comment: @Seth I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but I might have addressed that in my presentation of the Rosh Yosef.

Comment: Ok, in this case, why would it be permitted? Do we ever find that issurim derabbanan which are not permitted for ochel nefesh are nevertheless permitted on Yom Tov?

Comment: @wfb an issur dirabanan to cook on a day where cooking is completely assur would theoretically not transfer over to a day when cooking is allowed at times. Just a svara. I'm not actually pushing this Svara, or maintaining this issur is a dirabanan or that it would even matter if it was. I'm looking for sources discussing this law. I just threw in the Rosh Yosef for extra credit. If you see any parallel dinim which you think would shed light on this, that's not really what I'm looking for, but that's fine.