# Heter for Inviting Non-Jew to Hot Meal on Yom Tov

Tags: yom-tov, cooking-bishul

It is generally considered that a non-Jew cannot be invited to a hot meal on Yom-Tov because it is a melacha to heat up food for them (from what I've heard, even if it is as part of a group including Jews and there is plenty of food).  Is anyone aware of any heterim for this? (eg. for inviting people in the process of conversion)

Comment: As a non-Jew in an observant community, most Jews do not directly invite me.  Instead, they say that such and such is occurring, there will be food open to the community, etc. and I just show up. One reason, is that I'm not mekablin ger(tzedek) (I'm not accepted as a ger in the community since only gerei tzedek are accepted today, however I'm a ben Noach).

It's kind of funny, kind of sad, but it does seem a necessary fence.

Comment: It would be a problem if the food was specifically made for him but many people tend to overcook for yontiff so there is an abundance then whatever food on the table isn't a problem if he eats also

Comment: I have heard that according to mainstream opinions it is a problem to give him food that was cooked for Yom Tov even if it is as part of a group with Jews and that the amount of food available is irrelevant.  The only way around it that I've heard of so far is if he goes into the kitchen and takes the food himself.

Comment: The decree is not to feed him anything since you might need to worm up food just for him, (but on shabos there is no such decree since you can not worm up food for any body)

Comment: @EhevuTov I think you are misunderstanding the reason they are not allowed to invite you directly on Yom Tov (as opposed to on Shabbat). On Yom Tov, Jews are biblically prohibited from cooking for a weekday, whether for themselves or for others. For those who are not commanded to keep Yom Tov, ironically, Yom Tov itself is actually a weekday. As such, the Rabbis were concerned that if they invited you directly, they would also end up cooking specifically for you. This way, you're able to partake of actual Yom Tov food, rather than their violating Yom Tov by cooking for you weekday food.

Comment: Not sure why you think I don't understand

Comment: @EhevuTov Because you called it sad. I wasn't clear why you consider it sad.

Comment: Ah, I mean it's sad for us, as Bnei Noach because we're in an intermediary stage of acceptance. Ger Toshav is not accepted today, so we get placed into the geder of goy. So that means no play groups for our children, no Torah education, etc. Sad in an emotional sense. And of course we're not going to send our child to public school, so it's still a bit of a lonely existence, particularly for our child.

Comment: @EhevuTov That sounds pretty awful. Seems like it would be a lot easier to just become a full *ger tzedek*.

Answer (score 1):

In siman 512 the allowance given by the Mechaber is to cook for one's servant maid etc or a no-Jew who comes himself.

Mishna Berurah explains that the only time we have the concern of coming to cook specifically for a non-Jew is when they were important enough to invite. In that case we are afraid one may accidentally come to cook specifically for them which is a biblical prohibition.

Ramma adds that when cooking for himself, he can actually add extra food for the non-jew. This is only written about the non-Jew the Mechaber was talking about, a servant or maid. However this allowance does not extend to other non-jews. 
From the Aruch HaShulchan siff 6 it appears a person who shows up by himself would be included in the prohibited group.

Also in the Aruch HaShulchan siff 5 he brings another hetter to invite a non-Jew as long as the food was already cooked. The Aruch HaShulchan though goes on to explain that the situation cannot be that one had intended to invite him from before he started cooking. It would be impossible to say he didn't have this guest in mind when cooking. He says this only works if one cooked the food, and then bumped into this non-Jew close to meal time, and invited him to the completely ready meal.

One clarification though, you mention heating up food in your question. I would doubt heating up food that was previously cooked is included in this Rabbinic enactment. But clear that up with your religious authority.

Comment: Heating up liquids (as is common on YT) would be included, probably.

Comment: I possibly agree. I wrote heating food.

Comment: Ah right http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57876/759

Comment: Impressive:) But I have other reasons to wonder here. Even if reheating is cooking, as we might want to say by liquids, reheating may be low enough on the honor scale to have not been disallowed.

Comment: I don't think honoring is the issue. I think the leniencies of *melacha* on Yom Tov only apply biblically if they are for the food of Yom Tov. Cooking for someone not obligated in Yom Tov doesn't qualify as part of the *heter ochel nefesh* so it is no different than cooking on Shabbos, which means that if we assume reheating water is *bishul*, that would be the case on Yom Tov as well.

Comment: @Loewian the gezeira of not inviting him because we may come to cook for him which is assur midioraisa was specifically made in a case of an honorable invitation. As the achronim explain.

Comment: But that itself is out of concern for the biblical prohibition which would not distinguish between the two (as you note in your linked question).

Comment: @Loewian correct. First we must prove that reheating is real cooking though. Not just treated as if it was real. If we are only being stringent on shabbos to treat it as if, than there is room to wonder on Yom Tov.

Comment: @Loewian but even that linked question is not really the same as here. That was putting fresh water into a kli rishon which is off the fire. Here we are dealing with a mutar cooking which has an attached gezeira of not inviting someone you can't cook for just in case you do cook for him

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you - if we are assuming reheating water would be *chayyiv min hatorah* on Shabbos, why would we be any more lenient with regard to reheating water than with regard to roasting a piece of raw meat, even in terms of inviting someone for whom Yom Tov is *chol*?

Comment: @Loewian because we are not reheating it for him. If in fact reheating is real cooking than of course reheating water for him on Yom Tov is assur midioraisa. So let us view these laws now replacing all the words cooking with reheating. It will be assur to reheat for him. But we are not reheating for him. We are reheating for ourselves. There is a rabbinic prohibition not to invite him so as not to come to reheat for him. This prohibition has been explained to only apply to cases of an honorable invite. In this situation we are afraid that due to pressure, we might reheat expressly for him.

Comment: @Loewian so my question/haara Is this: does this gezeiar apply to the not honourable case of reheating.