# What is involved in moving items for the purpose of a non-Jew on Yom-Tov?

Tags: gentiles, yom-tov, muktzeh

A ball comes over the fence from the non-Jewish neighbours on Yom Tov.  Are there any halachic problems involved in returning the ball if there is an eruv in the area?

In the back of my mind I know I may [not cook](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67448/heter-for-inviting-non-jew-to-hot-meal-on-yom-tov) for a non-Jew on Yom Tov.

Comment: An Eruv does what for carrying on Yom Tov? Does it help for hotzaah shelo litzorech?

Comment: As I recall, the reason is that cooking is only allowed on Yom Tov for *tzorech ochel nefesh* (your own food - including other Jews). Thus, cooking for a nonJew is still forbidden, just as it is forbidden for everyone on Shabbos.